# Changing YouTube videos and descriptions

Tags: youtube

1. Once a YouTube video is uploaded, can I make changes to the video (i.e. re-upload a new video that will appear at the same URL)?
2. Can I change the description?
3. Or alternatively, can I make the YouTube URL forward to a new YouTube URL?

(I will be editing a video after it's uploaded, and I'll want to keep the newly edited video at the same URL.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You **cannot** make changes to the video once you uploaded it on YouTube. Each video has a unique URL that cannot be changed.
2. You can always change title, description, tags, and category. You need to go to your "Video Manager" page to change these.
3. You **cannot** forward a YouTube URL to a new YouTube URL.